# What is Worbli that is a fork of EOS?

Tags: blockchains, sidechain

What exactly is Worbli blockchain? Is it a fork of EOS and what problem does it solve that EOS cannot? Why didn't they just build on top of EOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worbli is a code fork of the EOS blockchain optimised for financial services, they have choose to be separate from the public blockchain to set different governance (centralised) and rules to optimise their services